# Angular is Based on Event Driven or Data Driven Model

Tags: javascript, angular, design-patterns

**Angular** is based on Event Driven or Data Driven Model.

using of **ngRx** follows which pattern data driven or event driven.

Comment: Do you mean under the hood or conceptually? Conceptually to keep *good action hygiene* you write event based ngrx actions

Comment: @AndrewAllen I am asking under the hood , I am curious to know on which model angular is based. and if we write actions in hygienic manner then does app will behave as event based.

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on your implementation.

If your implementation is based on CRUD, I guess you say it is data driven as any http requests will mutate state data that will eventually trigger UI update.

However, if your overall system is implemented in for example SignalR based architecture, then coming SignalR event shall dispatch ngrx actions with a playload to be able to mutate state. In this case, I guess you can say it is an event driven model.